# FIREBASE, variable when declared outside addDoc is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I am declaring the msg variable outside and passing it. The code doesn't gives any error, but the data doesn't gets stored in database. And the code doesn't even reach the last done alert statement.

But when i am hardcoding the Massage value in the key itself, it is working. Why is it so?

```
$("#msg-sent").click(async function (){
  alert("reached point 1");

  const msg="this is a msg";
  alert(msg);
  try {
    
    alert("in try block");
    await addDoc(collection(db, "users-messages"),{
      Name:"my name",
      Message:msg    //if i am giving the string directly here like Message:"this is a msg" then it is working
    });
    } catch (e) {
      alert("Message Not SENT");
      console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
    }
    alert("done");
});
```

Comment: What is the element with id `msg-sent`? Can you show it in the HTML code?

Comment: <form id="message-form">
   <input type="text" id="message-input" placeholder="message" required>
   <button class="orange-button" id="msg-sent">send</button>
  </form>

Comment: Does that solves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62312334/data-is-not-going-to-firebase-database-in-javascript/62312969#62312969

Comment: But in my case its already BUTTON...is there something else I should do?

Comment: I am not getting why it is not working if i am passing it with the help of a variable but is working if i hardcode it in there.

Comment: await addDoc(collection(db, "users-messages"),{
      Name:"my name",
      Message:"this is a msg"   });   //its working fine if i am doing this